# Is there a function to check if the session is not blank and equal to a certain variable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now in my code I am trying to check if specific session key/value exists, and if so, do something.  Is there a way to do all of this at once instead of multiple if statements?

Here are my if statements:

```
if session[:mysession] %>
  if session[:mysession][:cats] != "fluffy" %>
    #do something
  end
end
```

I get a nil error when I do this:

```
if session[:mysession][:cats] == "fluffy"
  #do something
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1)

```
if session[:mysession] && (session[:mysession][:cats] != "fluffy")
```

(2) (Especially good when there's a lot of code referencing session[:mysession])

```
session[:mysession] ||= {}
if session[:mysession][:cats] != "fluffy"
```

(3)

```
if session.fetch(:mysession, {})[:cats] != "fluffy"
```

Comment: Can you explain point 1 to me?  Why would that be ok compared to just using `session[:mysession][:cats] != "fluffy"`?

Comment: Your original question seemed to have concern that session[:mysession] might be nil, and raise an exception if dereferenced with [:cats].  The lazy evaluation of && if the left side is false or nil, it knows that the && expression will be false, without having to evaluate the right side.  So, if session[:mysession] is nil, the if will fail, but never call session[:mysession][:cats].

Comment: The one risk here with #1 is that if session[:mysession] is set to "false" (a legitimate value), it will fail the test and assume it is not set.   It doesn't necessarily apply to the :cats example, but in general applications one should be wary of doing a simple boolean test (because it might really be false.    You will never go wrong with (!foo.nil).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the try function. When called on nil it will silently return nil. You would "try" to call [] method with with your key as the argument

```
if session[:mysession].try(:[], :cats) == "fluffy"
    #do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if Hash(session[:mysession])[:cats] == "fluffy"
  % do something
end
```

In theory it tries to convert your session variable into a hash, and gets its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
 session['cats'] = Hash.new if session['cats'] == nil
 // do something
 @cat_session = session['cats']
```